# Celery Accepting more tasks than worker concurrency

Tags: celery, airflow, celery-task, airflow-scheduler

I am running few long running tasks in dedicated queue. So there are no short time running tasks.  Currently when i start many multiple tasks on one queue, the new tasks are getting submitted to the worker which is already full i.e no of tasks = worker concurrency. The worker 2 listening to same queue is still has less tasks and can accept more tasks. Ideally the task should go to worker 2.

What is the reason for this behaviour ? Is it because of prefetching ?

We further see that the task which got submitted to worker 1 which is already full, goes to worker 2 after sometime i.e around 2 hours. Why does this happen ? And why after 2 hours ? Is there a way to reduce the time the task goes from worker 1 to worker 2.

My late acknowledgement is set = true
and visibility timeout on worker = 6hrs. 
broker is redis.
celery version 4.2.1

I have attached few screenshot to catch this behaviour: 
My other worker is still empty, but it goes to the worker which is already full

I could go close to this only in this link http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/optimizing.html#reserve-one-task-at-a-time

Please check trailblazer.streaming.growth_fortune trailblazer-growth-fortune-stream-0001 2019-04-25T10:10:00 as an example.
The task got queued at 10:18 to worker 1, then after 2 hours, it started to run on worker 2 at 12:20. 
Screenshot 1: Celery Flower[image]
Screenshot 2: Airflow Ui [image]

Answer (score 0):

By default celery will [prefetch 4 tasks at a time](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#std:setting-worker_prefetch_multiplier). In short-running tasks this behavior is more efficient as the worker doesn't have to constantly return to the queue to get more tasks because it has a few already reserved to work on. In the case of long-running tasks like you have, it is likely that you want to "disable" prefetch by using the `-O fair` option as documented [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/optimizing.html#prefork-pool-prefetch-settings)